# What problems can occur if a view contains a value that exceeds its field's CHARACTER_MAX_LENGTH?

Tags: sql-server, view

If I have a **view** that has a column of length 1 that points to a column in a **table** that has length 2, then I am still able to select the value from the view, even though the value exceeds the length of the view's column.

See e.g. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/76a39/1

I am not sure why this is allowed, but could this cause any problems down the line, when the view is referenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make sure that the metadata about a view is always accurate, use the [`SCHEMABINDING`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) option when you create it:

> Binds the view to the schema of the underlying table or tables. When `SCHEMABINDING` is specified, the base table or tables cannot be modified in a way that would affect the view definition. The view definition itself must first be modified or dropped to remove dependencies on the table that is to be modified. When you use `SCHEMABINDING`, the *select_statement* must include the two-part names (*schema.object*) of tables, views, or user-defined functions that are referenced. All referenced objects must be in the same database.

Comment: That could be useful. But is there a problem with leaving the view definition as it is (as in my example)? Could anything break if I do so?

Comment: Yes, things could break. See also [`sp_refreshview`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx): "If a view is not created with schemabinding, **sp_refreshview** should be run when changes are made to the objects underlying the view that affect the definition of the view. Otherwise, the view might produce unexpected results when it is queried."